# Decorating classes in different namespaces overrides functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module, namespaces

**Scenario:**

I am attempting to decorate two controllers in the Spree framework:

```
Spree::Admin::ProductsController
```

and

```
Spree::ProductsController
```

Same class name, but different namespaces.

In the `Spree::Admin::ProductsController`, I created a `before_action`, declared like so:

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    ProductsController.class_eval do
      before_action :create_variant_options_array, only: [:edit]

      def create_variant_options_array
         # method details...
      end
   end
  end
end
```

**The Problem:**

Later, I attempted to open the `Spree::ProductsController`. I had only coded this,

```
module Spree
  ProductsController.class_eval do
    # nothing written here yet, at this point
  end
end
```

...when I noticed that the `before_action` in the `Spree::Admin::ProductsController` no longer fired. In fact nothing in the `Admin` version of the controller would execute anymore. The only solution was to comment out the `ProductsController.class_eval...` portion of the non-admin decorator.

In essence, the behaviour was as though the non-admin decorator was somehow affecting (overwriting) the admin decorator in the deeper structure.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what, exactly, is happening here. Among my "guesses" is that the non-admin `Spree::ProductsController` decorator is somehow being applied to the "deeper" version, however even if that is the case, I am unaware of any way that `.class_eval` would *remove* or *negate* functionality applied in another decorator. Alternatively, I may be doing something incredibly obvious, and I simply cannot see; however as stated, I am currently at a loss to explain this behaviour.

**Question:**

Given the described scenario, what might cause the `before_action` in the `Admin` decorator to cease functioning when the non-admin decorator is attempting to decorate a class of the same name in a different (higher) module / namespace?